# How to draw time series from CSV file in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, time-series

my CSV file is below:

| Entity | Code | Year | Total tax revenue (% of GDP) (ICTD (2021)) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Afghanistan | AFG | 2003 | 2.512631 |
| Afghanistan | AFG | 2004 | 4.07617 |
| Afghanistan | AFG | 2005 | 4.668273 |
| Afghanistan | AFG | 2006 | 6.061553 |
| Afghanistan | AFG | 2007 | 6.174382 |
| Afghanistan | AFG | 2008 | 8.673146 |
| Afghanistan | AFG | 2009 | 9.559737 |

Above is my table, could you please tell me how to draw the time series from this CSV file? or give me some hints on this. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to draw time series from CSV file, [first upload your data into python](https://datatofish.com/import-csv-file-python-using-pandas/) using 'pandas' 'Data Frame' and then plot figures/graphs of your data using 'matplotlib'.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

path = #enter the path of your csv file
df = pd.read_csv(path+'\data.csv')

df.plot(x='Year', y='Total tax revenue (% of GDP) (ICTD (2021))')
```

The code above will produce the following plot:
[image]

For more information and examples you can look [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/visualization.html), the visualization section of 'pandas'.